# Creating a large quantity of types VS using mostly the ones provided by the language

Tags: coding-style

There are several times where you're coding a method which has two parameters with the same type, lets say, integers, `NumberOfUnitA` and `NumberOfUnitB`. Given that we're coding in a language that doesn't support named parameters, why is that we don't see people creating types closer to the domain logic, in this case, `UnitA` and `UnitB`, but just raw integers? It seems much more expressive to me.

And even in other situations, many times, we have to pass a bunch of flags, and they are just integers (even in cases where perfomance is not an issue), why we do this? Does it create unnecessary complications?

What are the problems of this approach of creating many types?

Comment: Are you talking about the approach discussed in the [tiny types](http://darrenhobbs.com/2007/04/11/tiny-types/) blog post that Jon Skeet also [blogged about](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2014/01/31/how-many-32-bit-types-might-we-want.aspx)?

Comment: Exactly! So, it seems that some people have applied it with success already.

Answer (score 3):

The reason I am not doing it as much as I would like to: not enough compiler support.

In Delphi I can create type aliases such as:

```
type
  TAmount = type Integer;
  THouseNumber = type Integer;
  TCreditAmount = type Currency;
  TDebitAmount = type Currency;
```

These would make method signatures so much more self dosumenting. Unfortunately, the compiler doesn't force me to use the proper alias as long as the types are assignment compatible. Only if a parameter is a `var` parameter (passed by reference) does the compiler enforce exact type equality.

Which means that I can forget to use the proper types and won't be alerted. Which means that the code base may slowly start not using TCreditAmount where it should and that detracts from the usefulness of declaring it in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

This depends a lot of the language you use.

I Go which has type aliases you can easily create aliases for ints without any notable drawbacks.
Other languages don't allow deriving elementar types like int or string at all,  (like Dart) because they are strongly optimized for performance and dynamic method dispatch as it's used for polymorphism would decrease performance a lot (but Dart has named parameters though)

Comment: Many strongly typed languages allow aliasing elemental types.

Comment: I, guess so, and I hate it that I don't know more of them or that I already forgot about because I didn't use them for such a long time.